# Performing Authenticated Requests in Etsy API

Tags: c#, angular, api, etsy

I'm creating a proof of concept that leverages the Etsy API via C# along with Angular.

I'm currently having issues performing authenticated requests to the Etsy API and receive the following response when requesting the authenticated user's profile:

"No logged in user; please specify a user id instead"

Below is the Controller action that I am calling.

You'll notice that if `__SELF__` is passed in as the `userId` that the authentication code is called.  Otherwise that code is skipped.

I am able to retrieve user profile's when I pass in a valid user name/id.

```
        [HttpGet("{userId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UserProfile(string userId)
        {
            string requestUrl = String.Format("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/{0}/profile?api_key={1}", userId, AccountController.ConsumerKey);

            string token = Request.Headers["Access_Token"];
            string tokenSecret = Request.Headers["Access_Verifier"];

            if (userId.Equals("__SELF__"))
            {
                var client = new OAuthRequest
                {
                    Method = "GET",
                    Type = OAuthRequestType.ProtectedResource,
                    SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                    ConsumerKey = AccountController.ConsumerKey,
                    ConsumerSecret = AccountController.ConsumerSecret,
                    Token = token,
                    TokenSecret = tokenSecret,
                    RequestUrl = requestUrl,
                };              

                requestUrl += "&" + client.GetAuthorizationQuery();
            }


            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl))
            using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
            {
                string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (data != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        UserModel userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(data);
                        if (userInfo != null && userInfo.Count == 1 && userInfo.Results != null && userInfo.Results.Count == 1)
                        {
                            return Ok(userInfo.Results[0]);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return NotFound(data);
                    }
                }

                return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

I'm assuming that I am leveraging the OAuth Specific code incorrectly here.  I have tried using the token and verifier from the client as well as the token and token secret, but none appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by removing the api key from the request uri when a request is made with OAuth credentials.

```c
            string requestUrl = String.Format("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/{0}/profile", userId);

            if (userId.Equals("__SELF__"))
            {
                var client = new OAuthRequest
                {
                    Method = "GET",
                    Type = OAuthRequestType.ProtectedResource,
                    SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                    ConsumerKey = AccountController.ConsumerKey,
                    ConsumerSecret = AccountController.ConsumerSecret,
                    Token = token,
                    TokenSecret = tokenSecret,
                    RequestUrl = requestUrl,
                };              

                requestUrl += "&" + client.GetAuthorizationQuery();
            } else {
               requestUrl += String.Format("?api_key={0}", AccountController.ConsumerKey); 
            }
```